# How to initialize a function within an HTML file in a JavaScript file? (Chrome Apps)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am working with a Scoring Board Chrome App. (I am new to Chrome Apps)

**index.html** - (just a part of the code) where user inputs the number of players for the scoring board, submits and opens another html file where a table and a number of rows are displayed based on the user input.

```
<form class="pure-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter number of Players:</legend>

    <input type="text" id="users" placeholder="Input Number">
    <button type="submit" id="btn1" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
  function(){
    //localStorage.setItem('value', document.getElementById("users").value);
    localStorage.value = document.getElementById("users").value;
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main-sheet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/alert.js"></script>
```

**main-sheet.html** - (also just a part of the code)

```
<table class="pure-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Baluts</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function addMoreRows(){
    //var val = localStorage.getItem('value');
    var val = localStorage.value;

    document.getElementById("value").value = val;

    for(var x=0; x<val; x++) {
        var newRow = document.getElementById('pure-table').insertRow();

        var newCell = newRow.insertCell();
        newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input type='text' name='code'></td></tr>";

        newCell = newRow.insertCell();
        newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input type='text' name='name'></td></tr>";

        newCell = newRow.insertCell();
        newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input type='text' name='score'></td></tr>";

        newCell = newRow.insertCell();
        newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td><input type='text' name='baluts'></td></tr>";

    }
}
</script>
```

The table head is displayed but rows aren't. Though I see why because function addMoreRows() hasn't really been called, and I don't know how.

And here is for the **main-sheet.js**

```
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (!document.getElementById('users').value.trim()) {
        //alert("Please enter the remarks");
        chrome.app.window.create('../alert.html',{
          'bounds': {
            'width': 200,
            'height': 200
          },
          'resizable': false,
        });
    }
    else{
    chrome.app.window.create('../main-sheet.html', {
    'bounds': {
      'width': 1000,
      'height': 1000
    },
    'resizable': false,
  });
}});
```

How do I call the function addMoreRows() to add Rows??
I would appreciate the help and corrections. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried creating a button handler for the Submit button, and calling the addMoreRows() function from the handler?  That might be what you need.

Comment: @petewil-G not yet but I'll try maybe..

Comment: @petewil-G chrome apps does not support inline scripting.. I just wanna make sure if I'm doing this right? The thing with storing the input number value of the user from the index.html and then can be accessed or get by other html files, for example, the main-sheet.html (get value stored to be use in initializing the addMoreRows()) ?

Comment: **I just rolled back your question, and let me explain why.** You have asked a certain question, and it received a correct answer. You cannot change the question radically without invalidating that answer. Since you now have a different question, you should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @Xan sorry I didn't know that.. but thanks with that information.. Next time I'll be more careful with this.

Answer (score 2):

Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline blocks and inline event handlers. You have to include a script file containing your javascript in your page

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script">
```

instead of using your javascript code (addMoreRows()) as inline JS within the page.

You will find more info on the [Chrome Content-Security-Policy.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like reading the documentation would really help, particularly [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy) and [Disabled Web Features](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated). This means you cannot use localstorage and inline script.

Comment: But do localstorage and inline script work on Chrome extensions? Or what? Thank you for the links though.

Comment: I just wanna make sure if I'm doing this right? The thing with storing the input number value of the user from the index.html and then can be accessed or get by other html files, for example, the main-sheet.html (get value stored to be use in initializing the addMoreRows()) ?

Comment: `localStorage` works on extensions, but it's better to use `chrome.storage` for both. Inline scripts are disabled on both.

Comment: @Xan I'm working with chrome.storage now.. Some code still confuses.. Because I have to store a value from index.html and get that value for another html.. Still working on it. :/